# Is there a way to load data from all files in a directory using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, glob

**My question:** Is there a way to load data from all files in a directory using Python

**Input:** Get all files in a given directory of mine (wow.txt, testting.txt,etc.)

**Process:** I want to run all the files through a def function

**Output:** I want the output to be all the files names and their respective content below it.For example:

/home/file/wow.txt
"all of its content"
/home/file/www.txt
"all of its content"

---

**Here is my code:**

```
# Import Functions
import os
import sys

# Define the file path
path="/home/my_files"
file_name="wow.txt"

#Load Data Function
def load_data(path,file_name):
    """
    Input  : path and file_name
    Purpose: loading text file
    Output : list of paragraphs/documents and
             title(initial 100 words considered as title of document)
    """
    documents_list = []
    titles=[]
    with open( os.path.join(path, file_name) ,"rt", encoding='latin-1') as fin:
        for line in fin.readlines():
            text = line.strip()
            documents_list.append(text)
    print("Total Number of Documents:",len(documents_list))
    titles.append( text[0:min(len(text),100)] )
    return documents_list,titles

#Output
load_data(path,file_name)
```

**Here is my output:**

[image]

---

**My Problem** is that my output only takes one file and shows its content. Obviously, i defined the path and file name in my code to one file but I am confused as to how to write the path in a way to load all the files and output each of its contents separately. Any suggestions?

Comment: look for `os.listdir()` or `glob`, read all the files and their contents afterwards

Answer (score 4):

Using [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html):

```
import glob
files = glob.glob("*.txt")           # get all the .txt files

for file in files:                   # iterate over the list of files
    with open(file, "r") as fin:     # open the file
        # rest of the code
```

Using [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir):

```
import os
arr = os.listdir()    
files = [x for x in arr if x.endswith('.txt')]

for file in files:                   # iterate over the list of files
    with open(file, "r") as fin:     # open the file
       # rest of the code
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import glob

for file in glob.glob("test/*.xyz"):
    print(file)
```

if my directory name was "test" and I had lots of xyz files in them...

Comment: I accidentally published before finishing it :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use `glob` and pandas

import pandas as pd
import glob

```
path = r'some_directory' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.txt")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    #read file here
    # if you decide to use pandas you might need to use the 'sep' paramaeter as well
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)

# get it all together
frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will take advantage of the function you have already written, so use the following:

```
data = []
path="/home/my_files"
dirs = os.listdir( path )
for file in dirs:
    data.append(load_data(path, file))
```

In this case you will have all data in the list `data`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use a for loop on a listdir:

```
os.listdir(<path of your directory>)
```

this gives you the list of files in your directory, but this gives you also the name of folders in that directory

Answer (score 0):

Try generating a file list first, then passing that to a modified version of your function.

```
def dir_recursive(dirName):
    import os
    import re

    fileList = list()
    for (dir, _, files) in os.walk(dirName):
         for f in files:
             path = os.path.join(dir, f)
             if os.path.exists(path):
                 fileList.append(path)

    fList = list()
    prog = re.compile('.txt$')
    for k in range(len(fileList)):
        binMatch = prog.search(fileList[k])
        if binMatch:
            fList.append(binMatch.string)

    return fList

def load_data2(file_list):
    documents_list = []
    titles=[]
    for file_path in file_list:
        with open( file_path ,"rt", encoding='latin-1') as fin:
            for line in fin.readlines():
                text = line.strip()
                documents_list.append(text)
    print("Total Number of Documents:",len(documents_list))
    titles.append( text[0:min(len(text),100)] )
    return documents_list,titles

# Generate a file list & load the data from it
file_list = dir_recursive(path)
documents_list, titles = load_data2(file_list)
```